# How do I create a query to count occurrences of tag words for each user in a dataset

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I am pretty new to couchDB and having issues coming up with a query.

This is an example of the data set I am working with

```
{
 "_id": "data",
 "_rev": "3-b78ec99614827106f637148c73dbf876",
 "data": [
       {
       "id": 0,
       "tags": [
           "cupidatat",
           "mollit",
           "labore",
           "minim",
           "pariatur",
           "qui",
           "ipsum"
       ]
      },
      {
      "id": 1,
      "tags": [
           "ex",
           "cillum",
           "est",
           "et",
           "mollit",
           "mollit",
           "exercitation"
       ]
       }
```

This is my map function

```
function(doc) {
  for(var i in doc.data)
  { 
    var person = doc.data[i];
     for(var tag in person.tags)
       {
         emit(person.tags, 1);
       }
   }
 }
```

This is the reduce function

```
function(keys, values)
  {
    return sum(values);
  }
```

I am trying to produce results that will give me the number of occurrences of each tag for all the records like,

```
key               value  
"cupidatat"         1  

"mollit"            3
```

How do I fix it so I can get the right results?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are very close.  Using your sample doc I got the results you are looking for using this map function:

```
function(doc) {
  for (var i = 0; i < doc.data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < doc.data[i].tags.length; j++) {
      emit(doc.data[i].tags[j], 1);
    }
  }
}
```

and used the built-in reduce:

```
_sum
```

The following request returns JSON in the format you specify:

```
curl -X GET http://host:5984/db/_design/words/_view/count?reduce=true&group_level=1
```